# Univariate time series for multiple devices

Tags: time-series, univariate

I have about 50k devices, which either fail (0) or connect (1). I have data for the past 300 days for all of them. I'm trying to predict when a device will next fail. The devices are all more or less the same type.

So, I have a matrix like
Device 1: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...]
Device 2: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....]
Device 3: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ....]
...

And trying to predict the next column.

So far, I've tried XGBoost / deep gated recurrent nets. I'm wondering if there's a better approach.

I think the data from all 50k devices should be pooled in some way, then the final prediction should be tailored to the characteristics of the individual device. Not sure how to do this statistically.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered survival analysis?

Comment: No I haven't. Thank you for recommending this; are there good resources I should read online?

Comment: Never mind, I just saw that your devices are failing and connecting multiple times. What other variables do you have? Can you show us a plot of one device for the DV through time? The sequence of fails and connects.

Comment: Sure. Is it OK if I copy paste it? This is one such device.
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: OK, so what other variables do you have that can help in the classification? Also are the connections and fails independent?

Comment: hmm, we have a couple other variables like signal strength. just using some XGBoost it doesn't seem to help much though. I am thinking about combining past data with the variables, maybe it will help.

also, connections and fails are not necessarily independent between different devices only because the same software might have a bug, but I think we can weakly assume independence (it's not a wifi network haha).

Comment: Well you need some variables to try and explain the outcomes, what causes these failures. Otherwise a survival analysis could be done (maybe), that would tell you what the probability is that any device would fail in the next unit of time.